# Get vuex module state in another module action

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, vuex

I'm a little bit confused with vuex store component.

How should I obtain state of another module? 
I tried a different ways to get data from store and always got Observer object. What is the correct way to **knock knock** to observer?

[image: Observer object]

If I try to get anything from this object directly, like `rootState.user.someVariable` then I got undefined response.

Don't have a problem getting state from components.

**Edit**. Add code

User module

```
import * as Constants from './../../constants/constants'
import * as types from '../mutation-types'
import axios from 'axios'

const state = {  user: [] }

    const getters = {
       getUser: state => state.user
    }

const actions = {
getUserAction ({commit}) {
    axios({method: 'GET', 'url': Constants.API_SERVER + 'site/user'})
      .then(result => {
        let data = result.data
        commit(types.GET_USER, {data})
      }, error => {
        commit(types.GET_USER, {})
        console.log(error.toString())
      })
  }
}

const mutations = {
 [types.GET_USER] (state, {data}) {
    state.user = data
  }
}

export default { state, getters, actions, mutations }
```

Mutatinos

```
export const GET_LANGS = 'GET_LANGS'
export const GET_USER = 'GET_USER'
```

Store

```
import Vuex from 'vuex'
import Vue from 'vue'
import user from './modules/user'
import lang from './modules/lang'

Vue.use(Vuex)    
const store = new Vuex.Store({
      modules: {
    user,
    lang
  }
})
```

Main app

```
import Vue from 'vue'
import App from './App'
import router from './router'
import store from './store/index'

Vue.config.productionTip = false

    new Vue({
      el: '#app',
      router,
      store,
      template: '<App/>',
      components: { App }
    })
```

Lang module, here is the place where I'm trying get store

```
import * as types from '../mutation-types'
import {axiosget} from '../../api/api'    

const state = {  langList: [] }

const getters = {
  getLangs: state => state.langList
}

const actions = {
// this two action give me similar result
  getLangsAction (context) {
    axiosget('lang') // described below
  },
  getAnotherLangsAction (context) {
    console.log(context.rootState.user) <----get Observer object
  }
}

const mutations = {
  [types.GET_LANGS] (state, {data}) {
    state.langList = data
  }
}

 export default { state, getters, actions, mutations }
```

axiosget action, api module

```
  import * as Constants from './../constants/constants'
import store from '../store/index'
import axios from 'axios'

    export const axiosget = function (apiUrl, actionSuccess, actionError) {
      console.debug(store.state.user) // <----get Observer object, previously described
      // should append user token to axios url, located at store.state.user.access_token.token
      axios({method: 'GET', 'url': Constants.API_URL + apiUrl 
 + '?access_token=' + store.state.user.access_token.token})
        .then(result => {
          let data = result.data
          // todo implement this
          // }
        }, error => {
          if (actionError && actionError === 'function') {
           // implement this
          }
        })
    }
```

Component, that call dispatcher. If i get state via mapGetters in computed properties - there is no problems

```
<template>
    <div>
   {{user.access_token.token}}
    </div>
</template>

<script>
  import { mapGetters } from 'vuex'

  export default {
    name: 'ArticlesList',
    computed: mapGetters({
      user: 'getUser'
    }),
    created () {
      this.$store.dispatch('getLangsAction')
      this.$store.dispatch('getAnotherLangsAction')
    }
  }
</script>
```

What I'm trying to do in this code - get user access token in main site (after login) and all further manipulations with data will be produced via api host.

Comment: Define `module`. You're not giving us much to go on with this, can you provide an example of what you want rather than a screenshot of some console logging ...

Comment: Probably a [Vuex module](https://vuex.vuejs.org/en/modules.html)

Comment: `rootState` should work. Show us the code that fails with `rootState`.

Answer (score 0):

Let's say you want to fetch state an attribute `userId` from object `userDetails` in Vuex store module `user.js`.

```
userDetails:{
  userId: 1,
  username: "Anything"
}
```

You can access it in following way in `action`

```
authenticateUser(vuexContext, details) {
  userId = vuexContext.rootState.user.userDetails.userId;
}
```

Note: After `rootState` and before file name `user`, add the path to the store module file if it is inside nested folders.